# Comparable in custom sorting instead of Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

When I search about difference between Comparable and Comparator interface in Java, Most of the time I got the the answer that Comparator can be used for customize sorting. Can you please answer Following question?
**1) Why we can not use the Comparable in custom sorting instead of Comparator?** (At the end both have method that returns int after comparison.)

Note: **Please  be stick to the question. I am not looking for the definition of the two interfaces.**

Comment: ***Quick***: Write me a class with three fields, *`firstName`*, *`lastName`* and *`birthDate`*. Now, make it `Comparable` (use the `lastName`). Finally, how do you make a program that can also sort by `firstName` and `birthDate`?

Comment: You can only implement `Comparable` once on a given class.

Answer (score 0):

Comparable is the interface that is to be implemented by the class that is to be ordered. To keep it simple you can compare instances only in one way using that interface.

You may have multiple comparators implemented for a single class. For example if you are dealing with people one can compare them based on birth date, one based on their name etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both **Comparable** and **Comparator** can be used for custom sorting but there are some differences in their usage.

- `Comparable` interface can be used to provide one way of sorting
  whereas `Comparator` interface can be used to provide multiple ways of
  sorting.
- For using `Comparable`, the Class needs to implement it whereas for using `Comparator` we don’t need to make any change in the class.
- For using `Comparable` we don’t need to make any code changes at client side. Arrays.sort() or Collections.sort() methods automatically uses the compareTo() method of the class. 
  But, to use `Comparator`, client needs to provide the `Comparator` class to be used in compare() method.

So based on the above needs you can choose either `Comparable` interface or `Comparator` interface